# JSESSIONID not working as expected in Jmeter

Tags: oracle, cookies, jmeter, oracle-adf, jsessionid

I'm working on a stress/test project for a application that uses ADF 11g.
I've recorded the log in process with Jmeter test script recorder.

My steps were:

1. Open up the site
2. Type in Username and Password
3. Click login

I have extractors and Cookie Manager set up correctly and replaced all the afrLoops, JsessionID, javax.faces.ViewState...etc

When I run the thread in Jmeter, the Login step respond always shows that it times up caused by inactivity.

So I looked deeper into it.
I used chrome's inspect element feature and check out the JSESSIONID while performing the steps live.
I saw that the JSESSIONID at the login page and the JSESSIONID after login are different.

but in my Jmeter test the JSESSIONID stays the same before and after login.
Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a different JSESSIONID after logon - is normal.
please have a look at this blog: http://soadev.blogspot.ro/2014/04/jmeter-load-test-oracle-adf-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

I am also testing a website having two JSESSION Ids before and after login. Jmeter cookie manager stores only the latest JSESSION id. If you try to check in Chrome's Inspect element, you will find that after login your cookie value get changed and that's what Jmeter Cookie manager is storing. Therefore, when you check cookie value in debug sampler, you will get only one JSESSION id